# Laravel 5.7 Validation Rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-5.7

When I submit a form, this is what I do to validate my fields...

```
<?php

$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => __('required|max:255|unique:templates,name,NULL,id,company_id,:company_id', [
        'company_id' => $request->input('companies')
    ]),
    'modules' => 'required|numeric',
    'companies' => 'required|numeric',
    'start_date' => 'required_with:limited_availability|date|before:end_date',
    'end_date' => 'required_with:limited_availability|date|after:start_date',
    'indesign_location' => __('required|file|mimetypes:application/zip|max::max_upload_size', [
        'max_upload_size' => config('file.max_size')
    ])
]);
```

**What I want to achieve:**
The fields `start_date` and `end_date` should only be required (and therefore be validated) when the field `limited_availability` is present.

**What happens now:** I don't get the message that the field is required, but I do get an error message on both date fields that the specified date is invalid.

The `limited_availability` is a checkbox and both `start_date` and `end_date` are date input fields.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you dump the submitted value of `limited_availability`. Actually not sure how the `required_with` validation works, but if the value of `limited_availability` is always submitted, it will always pass the validation rule.

Comment: "What happens now is that I don't get the message that the field is required, but I do get an error message on both date fields that the specified date is invalid." If date fields are present, then it does not break required.. validation so there is no error about that? If you tried without one date parameter and it says like this, than it basically does not see limited_availability as present. You sure you send them? Check $request variable to see if it exists.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I'm 100% sure the `limited_availability` field is not present in the post. I've checked for that. That is, when I don't check the checkbox, when I do check it, it is present in the request.

Comment: @mutas The `limited_availability` is not send when I haven't checked the checkbox (see my comment above). My goal is to make the field required and check the date only when `limited_availability` is checked.

Comment: I have no more idea. But i would check the request with dd($request->all());, return $request->all();, or with debug tools, when i checked the checkbox and not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is a naive solution. But I am pretty sure this will works.

```
// First thing we separate the validation rule and save it in a variable
$rules = [
    'name'                 => __( 'required|max:255|unique:templates,name,NULL,id,company_id,:company_id', [
        'company_id' => $request->input( 'companies' )
    ] ),
    'modules'              => 'required|numeric',
    'companies'            => 'required|numeric',
    'indesign_location'    => __( 'required|file|mimetypes:application/zip|max::max_upload_size', [
        'max_upload_size' => config( 'file.max_size' )
    ] )
];

// the solution is here
if ($request->has('limited_availability')) {
    $rules['start_date'] = 'required|date|before:end_date';
    $rules['end_date']   = 'require|date|after:start_date';
}

$this->validate( $request, $rules);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does. But I was kinda hoping it was possible in a single string without any other if/ else statements. It looks like this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using either of these validation rules. Put Comma and it will consider it as second parameter.

```
'start_date' => 'required_if:limited_availability,'
'end_date' => 'required_if:limited_availability,' 

or

 'start_date' => 'required_without:limited_availability,'
 'end_date' => 'required_without:limited_availability,'
```

Comment: Thanks, but required_if requires 2 parameters, so that should be `required_if:limited_availability,1` if I'm correct. When I try it like that, I still get the message that the specified date is invalid.